# BEGINNER: Why is my code executing a fourth guess when the limit is set to three max?

Tags: python

Below code runs fine if your guesses are within the "three-guess" limit, but if you guess wrong the third time, the guess-task asks once more for some reason. This is not what I want. And even if you get it right the third time, the program finishes. What to do?

Code:

```
    secret_number = 6 #random.randint(1, 12)
    print("We are going to play a guessing game.")
    guess_count = 3
    guess = int(input('Try figuring out the computers number between 1 and     12: '))
    while guess_count > 0:
        if int(guess) != int(secret_number):
            if int(guess) > int(secret_number):
                guess = input('Too high. Try again: ')
                guess_count = guess_count - 1
            elif int(guess) < int(secret_number):
                guess = input('Too low. Try again: ')
                guess_count = guess_count - 1
        elif int(guess) == int(secret_number):
            print("THAT'S CORRECT!")
            break
    else:
        print("Well, you tried.")
```

Output:

```
    We are going to play a guessing game.
    Try figuring out the computers number between 1 and 12: 12
    Too high. Try again: 1
    Too low. Try again: 4
    Too low. Try again: 6
    Well, you tried.
```

Comment: You have an input before you start your while loop, so you are giving away a free guess before you start deducting from `guess_count`

Answer (score 2):

Each time the user guesses incorrectly in the loop, `guess_count` is decreased by 1 and the `input` function is called asking the user to guess again. So this will be done three times; but the `input` function is also used before the loop, giving the user one extra guess.

To fix it, you could set `guess_count` to 2 before the loop, so that the user gets two guesses in the loop, making three in total including the one before the loop. But it is probably better to use the `input` function only at the start of the loop, not before the loop and not after an incorrect guess; the way you have it at the moment, the user will be asked again after an incorrect guess even if they have no guesses left.

Comment: I tried that and it had the same problem but with one less guess. When set to 3 like it is, it brings up a fourth guess, although a correct answer will result in only the ‘well you tried’ line popping up. When set to 2 it does the same thing but on the third guess.

Comment: I couldn’t figure out how to put the “try to guess the computers number” line in the loop, while also keeping the programs ability to tell you higher or lower. Because it would repeatedly post the “try to guess” line after an incorrect guess. I’ll play around some more with moving things.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. You are asking for input 3 times inside the while-loop and one time initially, so total 4 times. Also if the last prediction is correct, you are not checking it with the original value as you have used an elif condition. You can do it like this.

```
secret_number = 6 #random.randint(1, 12)
print("We are going to play a guessing game.")
guess_count = 2
correct_answer = False
guess = int(input('Try figuring out the computers number between 1 and     12: '))
while guess_count > 0:
    if int(guess) != int(secret_number):
        if int(guess) > int(secret_number):
            guess = input('Too high. Try again: ')
            guess_count = guess_count - 1
        elif int(guess) < int(secret_number):
            guess = input('Too low. Try again: ')
            guess_count = guess_count - 1
    if int(guess) == int(secret_number):
        correct_answer = True
        print("THAT'S CORRECT!")
        break
if correct_answer == False:
    print("Well, you tried.")
```

Comment: If this helps, please upvote/accept the answer. Happy coding. @isuckatpython

Comment: It worked, I just had to switch your true and false around because it was outputting “well you tried” after a win because the statement would be true

Comment: I guess you can accept the answer, even if you can't upvote @isuckatpython

Comment: It said something like “since you aren’t high enough level, your vote will be recorded but not shown” lol

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you are giving free guess at the top because you are `input` the first guess. It prints `Well, you tried` because `guess_count` is 0 at the last call, satisfying `else` statement. 
For debugging purpose, if you print `guess_count` in the `else` statement, you might be able to figure out.

Also You don't have to keep convert variable to `int`. The following is how I changed the code.

```
secret_number = 6 #random.randint(1, 12)
print("We are going to play a guessing game.")
guess_count = 3

while guess_count > 0:
    guess = int(input('Try figuring out the computers number between 1 and     12: '))  
    if guess != secret_number:
        if guess > secret_number:
            print('Too high. Try again: ')
            guess_count = guess_count - 1
        elif guess < secret_number:
            print("Too low. Try again: ")
            guess_count = guess_count - 1

    elif guess == secret_number:
        print("THAT'S CORRECT!")
        break
else:
    print("Well, you tried.")
```

Comment: Yea I kept getting “can’t compare nonetype - int” or “str to int” so I just went overboard with the int() to make sure they were all on the same page lol

Comment: the `secret_number` is already `int`. And since you are converting your input as you get it, it should be `int` type as well

Comment: Yea I just fixed it. I didn’t have my “too high guess again” answer preceded by an int() so it wasn’t recorded as such